# Claims Authentication - set time out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I exhausted google looking for a solution to this, I have claims authentication integrated into my application all is working as expected.

The issue I have is if the user doesn't click sign out they will remain logged in, with Claims can I set a timeout? say for example user is signed in automatically log them out within 60 minutes?

This is how I have CLaims Authentication configured which is different to the code example you provided:

```
 var userCredentials = new[]
        {
            new Claim("UserId", userProfile.UserId.ToString()),
            new Claim("Username", userProfile.UserName)
        };

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(userCredentials, "Forms");

        var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
        var token = new SessionSecurityToken(cp);

        var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
        sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

Update

Ok so after being told about time span I then added it to my SessionSecurityToken it has a time span of ten minutes as shown here:

```
  var token = new SessionSecurityToken(cp, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
```

yet when I debug this it shows a complete different time to what I expect, currently where I am its 20:42 at night (Australia, Melbourne) yet when I look at the valid from / valid to for the SessionSecurityToken is shows as

ValidFrom = {14/09/2015 10:42:49}
ValidTo = {14/09/2015 10:52:49}

And i'm not sure why?

This is what I have in my config:

```
<system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration>
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel">
      <sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="00:10:00" />
    </add>
  </securityTokenHandlers>
</identityConfiguration>
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here - the `SessionSecurityToken` constructor has an override that offers a `TimeSpan` that will allow you to designate how long the token is valid for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158905%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @BrendanGreen thanks for the suggestion, I have implemented this but it doesn't give me what I expect, i.e not authorised and get re-direct back to the login page instead it remains logged in? I've updated my question which example and web config, any chance you could take a look for me?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your question you could easily add a life time as time span in `SessionSecurityToken` constructor. But you are seeing different time than you expected because `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` is UTC time **not** local time. Hence Melbourne's time zone is UTC+10 therefore 10 hour different is completely normal.

Comment: I don't have that options, I've amended my question with code

Comment: I have updated my post to answer your updated question.

Comment: Right, well when I looked at it , it was 8pm here at night yet it was valid to 10am the same day so realistically it should of expired?

Comment: It should expire after 10 minutes you had set the cookie. From and To is not local time. If you set at 8pm is should expire at 8:10pm. UTC time is same in entire world. And completely independent from location.

Comment: That's what I would of thought, but it doesn't seem to do that.  I Signed In went and made a coffee then had a meeting (Roughly away from my desk for an hour) came back and clicked my profile yet I was still authorized ?